# How to confiugre AMD monaco editor for nuxtjs 2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Any help would be highly appreciated. Cannot figure out how to use AMD monaco editor (latest) with nuxtjs2.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Please provide a reproduction or any leads of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I also used the Monaco editor in my nuxt.js project.
That's why I refer this link you to https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxt-monaco-editor and this solution work for me. I hope this solution might be helpful for you also